# Asp.net MVC application displaying html content in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httpresponse, content-type

I am facing a very strange problem with my web application developed in ASP.Net MVC 3. Time to time it directly displays HTML source in browser. This issue comes randomly with different urls.

After I checked the content type returned using Google chrome debugger I found content type being returned form server is **txt/vnd.wap.wml**

I haven't written anything which takes care of wap or mobile based client.

URL from which I am getting issue right now is  : [live url](http://www.mobilecost.in/mobile/pricerange/from-15000-to-20000).

Can someone suggest why this is happening and how to fix it.

---

[image: Attaching a snap to make issue more clear]

Comment: This may be of help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176947/asp-net-mvc-keeps-overriding-text-html-content-type-with-wml?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for sharing .. I'll try adding a default content type using filters